# How to specify command arguments for bind -x based on history?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, line-editor

Let's say I have a command called synopsis that takes the name of a command  as an argument and prints out its syntax. Now I want to bind the synopsis to a key sequence. How can I pass the name of the command in the current command line to synopsis? This is an example of the desired behavior:

```
1$ bind -x '"\C-h": synopsis !#:0'
2$ ls -F^H 
<ls syntax print out from synopsis> 
3$ ls -F
```

Synopsis is invoked in 2, but there's no history expansion. I get the string '!#:0' instead of 'ls'. Nothing seems to work :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a function that is bound to a key, you can access and modify the current content of the command line through the variables [`READLINE_LINE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-READLINE_005fLINE) and [`READLINE_POINT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-READLINE_005fPOINT). Proof-of-concept (untested code):

```
synopsis () (
  set -f
  IFS=$'\t\n\r ;&|'
  words=($READLINE_LINE)
  while [[ "${words[1]}" == @([<>]*|[A-Za-z0-9_]##=) ]]; do
    shift words
  done
  command=${words[1]}
  "$command" --help
)
bind -x '"\C-h": synopsis'
```

The method you tried with history expansion can't work. History expansion is performed when a command line is executed. When invoking a binding, there's no history to expand.

But your fundamental problem is that [your shell isn't cool enough](http://www.slideshare.net/jaguardesignstudio/why-zsh-is-cooler-than-your-shell-16194692). This feature already exists in zsh, it's called [`run-help`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-run_002dhelp_002c-use-of).

```
bash$ echo 'autoload run-help' >~/.zshrc
bash$ zsh
darkstar% ls -FAlt+h
```

Comment: This will work just fine, thank you. One of these days I will start exploring alternative shells. Would be nice to have one based on python improved syntax :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `bind` without `-x`, inserting `synopsis` at the beginning of the line:

```
bind "'\C-h": "\C-asynopsis \C-j"
```

That would be ok with one argument. A more complex version would be:

```
bind '"\C-h": "\C-e !#:0\e^\e\C-] \C-usynopsis\C-j"'
```

Breaking it down:

```
'\C-e '    end-of-line
' !#:0'    insert space and 1st argument of current line
'\e^'      history-expand-line
'\e\C-] '  character-search-backward (to last space)
'\C-u'     unix-line-discard (delete to beginning of line)
'synopsis' insert 'synopsis' in front of the first argument
'\C-j'     accept-line
```

This handles a line with multiple arguments, running `synopsis` with the first argument only. (I'd also maybe use `"\C-xh"` or `"\eh"` instead of `"\C-h"`, which may already be erase/backspace/"backward-delete-char".)

Comment: Actually, I am using the F1 key for it, which requires a more elaborated solution. Thanks.